# Patch ELF (arm): remove constructor segment

Tags: elf, arm

I got an ELF shared library with a constructor function that is executed every time the library is loaded:

```
.init_array:00005E5C ; =====================================================================
.init_array:00005E5C
.init_array:00005E5C ; Segment type: Pure data
.init_array:00005E5C                 AREA .init_array, DATA
.init_array:00005E5C                 ; ORG 0x5E5C
.init_array:00005E5C                 DCD sub_239C
.init_array:00005E60                 DCB    0
.init_array:00005E61                 DCB    0
.init_array:00005E62                 DCB    0
.init_array:00005E63                 DCB    0
.init_array:00005E63 ; .init_array   ends
.init_array:00005E63
```

This constructor calls the function sub_239C:

```
.text:0000239C
.text:0000239C ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:0000239C
.text:0000239C ; Attributes: thunk
.text:0000239C
.text:0000239C sub_239C ; DATA XREF: .init_array:00005E5Co
.text:0000239C                 B sub_1354
.text:0000239C ; End of function sub_239C
.text:0000239C
```

Is there any way for me to remove the constructor and make `sub_239C` exported symbol